# How to set up an event handler from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm trying to understand how events in JavaScript work, and I have a VERY simple question. Say the following code:

```
const client = require('someLibrary')
let eventSource;
client.on('event', => {
   eventSource = client.someRandomThing
})
eventSource.on('event', => {
   // Anything here doesn't work.
})
```

I understand why the code won't work. The eventSource.on() is defined before the client.on('event'), but how would I create the eventSource handler AFTER eventSource changes from null (inside the client.on() section)?

This isn't a duplicate question, because I understand how to view a variable after it's been changed, but how would I directly call a handler?

Comment: so do you want to set a handler in a function; or fire an event in a function so that the handler is called?

Comment: "The logic that depends on the asynchronous function execution should be started/called from inside this asynchronous function... because the result is available at that point." https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667087/3345375 ...

Comment: ... so in your code, `eventSource.on('event', => { ... });` needs to be inside the function block `client.on('event', => { ... })` and it needs to be after `eventSource = client.someRandomThing;`.